# PHP - Edit Request Being Made by Other Request to the Server?

Tags: php, html, curl, request, src

everyone.

I'm working with cURL to download some page from a website. After the webpage loads, it makes a few other requests to the server to get some files from the server to load into the HTML (different images I want to compare that are randomized - they're a few decorating images that are randomizes, if that matters - a few are displayed, selected randomly from a set of images).

I want to load the images for the comparisons via cURL, but only after the page finished downloading.

Right now, in the webpage I get from the request I made, I get `<img>`s, but their `src`s are wrong, because they're stored locally on the server I'm fetching the webpage from.
Because of that, the page on the original page on the website is able to get the picture (since it's running on that server), yet I'm unable to get them successfully.

I already have the page in as a string variable. I know the address of the page and the URL/paths of the images, but I don't want to make another request to the server, because then the images would be randomized, and I want to do the comparisons between then after the page loads.

How can I do that? Is it possible to make a a request? Is it possible to somehow change my existing request of the page, or modify anything else that would bring me the images?

I know how to make requests, but I've never dealt with this kind of a "depth" of requests.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: just make sure to save the cookies you get from the original request (which probably includes a session id), and send that in the image request, then it will look to the server like it's just the request from the <img src

Comment: Are you sure that it wouldn't generate new images?
Would it return the same unique images?

I have a sessionID (the server is running ASP.NET), but I don't know if the images are generated on unique cookies' sessionIDs or not.